# sphinx search engine. number of items in "matches" not equal to "total"

Tags: php, sphinx

So I use sphinx search server (0.99) with Sphinx PHP PECL extension. I've configured searchd to pull data from my mysql database table. There is 419 records in that table.
code:

```
$s = new \SphinxClient;
$s->setServer("localhost", 9312);
$s->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
$s->setMaxQueryTime(3);
$result = $s->query( '', 'my_index' );
die( print_r( $result ) );
```

So - total in the result says correct number: 419, but result "matches" only contain 20 or so numbers. I expected that "matches" would contain 419 primary key numbers.... unless I'm misunderstansding how sphinx works....

any help?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at Apache Solr; especially its querying capabilities. I've used both Sphinx as well as Solr for my company and Solr won hands down on almost every front.

Comment: @techfoobar solr needs java installed and running? right? Also - Sphinx just released 2.03 version which should be greatly improved supposedly.

Comment: My app was on grails, so java was a given. Still solr's querying caps (especially related to spatial search) is just awesome. So switched to it. Sphinx is not bad by the way. Indexing speed was noted to be better than solr, but then indexing was done offline, so it didn't really matter much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for SetLimits, note the 'defaults' (the second paragraph is the most important)

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setlimits